# Usage of a clause to modify an い-adjective?

Tags: grammar

近所のバーは友達とお酒を飲むのにちょうどいい場所だ。
The neighbourhood bar is a great place to have a drink with friends.

Does one think of the dependent clause 友達とお酒を飲むのに as modifying the い-adjective ちょうどいい (which then modifies 場所), or does it modify the main clause ちょうどいい場所だ ? I'm aware that nouns can be modified by putting a clause in front (e.g. ぼくが食べたりんご), but to my knowledge this doesn't apply to い-adjectives. Perhaps I'm overthinking this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, feel free to think of it however you want, as long as it helps you understand how the sentence works. Secondly, this may not be a question with an objective answer. What follows are several considerations concerning the structure of *飲むのに良い場所だ*, shortened for briefness' sake.

【A】→【B】 means that B is modified by A.

To address one of your concerns, i-adjectives cannot be modified by a 連体形-clause the way a noun can be modified. Thus, a sentence like **【酒を飲む→良い】→【場所だ】* is wrong, you need the particle(s) *のに*. However, it can be parsed as *【酒を飲む】→【良い→場所だ】*, with *飲む* modifying *場所*, but it means something different: *A great place, where one drinks Sake.*

We could translate the sentence as *A place that is great for drinking*, which we could choose to interpret either as *(A place that is great.)(For drinking.)* or equally plausibly as *(A place that is:)(Great for drinking.)*

In a sense, many particles work like grammatical cases (or some  prepositions) in that they establish the relationship of a noun to the sentence. So *for drinking* marks drinking as the goal of the sentence's verb action; and that is how I think about *するのに甲だ*.

Comment: +1 the parentheses are really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the well-written answer!
What does するのに甲だ mean? Missed it the first time I read your answer.

Comment: 「〜するのに甲だ」The 甲 is a general placeholder (like the English "To do X"), so for example, you get the sentence from your question when you set 甲=「恰度良い場所」. The sequence continues 甲・乙・丙・丁 See here http://ci.lang.japan.narkive.com/dFvajLYs/kou-otsu-hei-means-abc-123 (Also, 甲=こう sounds like こう=like this...)

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole main clause is, as if it were a noun, modified by what precedes it. Within the main clause, ちょうどいい場所だ, ちょうど modifies いい, which, modified, in its turn modifies 場所.